# Cropping Python lists by value instead of by index

Tags: python, list, plot, crop, slice

Good evening, StackOverflow.
Lately, I've been wrestling with a Python program which I'll try to outline as briefly as possible.

In essence, my program plots (and then fits a function to) graphs. Consider [this graph.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/axth1.png)
The graph plots just fine, but I'd like it to do a little more than that: since the data is periodic over an interval **OrbitalPeriod** (1.76358757), I'd like it to start with our *first x value* and then iteratively plot all of the points  **OrbitalPeriod** away from it, and then do the same exact thing over the next region of length **OrbitalPeriod**.

I know that there is a way to slice lists in Python of the form

```
croppedList = List[a:b]
```

where *a* and *b* are the indices of the first and last elements you'd like to include in the new list, respectively. However, I have no idea what the indices are going to be for each of the values, or how many values fall between each **OrbitalPeriod**-sized interval.

What I want to do in pseudo-code looks something like this.

> croppedList = fullList on the domain [a + (N * **OrbitalPeriod**), a + (N+1 * **OrbitalPeriod**)]

where **a** is the x-value of the first meaningful data point.

If you have a workaround for this or a cropping method that would accept values instead of indices as arguments, please let me know. Thanks!

Comment: Try writing a function that returns the indices of list elements that are close (*enough*) to the intervals.  You could iterate over the list and check each element against the value of the first interval, when you find it save the index, then increment the interval and continue checking the list elements.  [enumerate](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) will probably help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are working with `numpy`, you can use it inside the brackets

```
m = x
M = x + OrbitalPeriod
croppedList = List[m <= List]
croppedList = croppedList[croppedList < M]
```